# Inserting in two tables with a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, zend-framework

I am developing a web app using zend framework and the problem is about combining 2 sql queries for improving efficiency. My table structure is like this

```
>table message
id(int auto incr)
body(varchar)
time(datetime)

>table message_map
id(int auto incr)
message_id(forgain key from message table's id column)
sender(int ) comment 'user id of sender'
receiver(int) comment 'user id of receiver'
```

To get the code working, I am first inserting the message body and time to the message table and then using the last inserted id, I am inserting message sender and receiver to message_map table. Now what I want to do is to do this task in a single query as using one query will be more efficient. Is there any way to do so.

Comment: If this is about one or two queries (and not thousands that run at once), you're probably wasting your time trying to optimize this.

Comment: One query is just a sample, actually this is gonna be used in a loop, probably thousands of times. I just wanna learn the trick to optimize my whole code.

Comment: fair enough. I think in this case however, there is no way around using two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. You can insert in only one table at once.

But I can't imagine you need to insert so much messages that performance really becomes an issue. Even with these separate statements, any database can easily insert thousands of records a minute.

**bulk inserts**
Of course, when inserting multiple records in the *same* table, that's a different matter. This is indeed possible in MySQL and it will make your query a lot faster. It will give you trouble, though, if you need to insert_ids from all those records.

mysql_insert_id() returns the first id that is inserted in the last insert statement, if it is a bulk insert. So you could query all id's that are >= that id. It should give you all records you just inserted, although the result may contain id's that other people inserted between your insert and the following query for those ids.

Comment: while working with serious projects, performance is always an issue. I am trying to find all the ways in which I can improve the performance of my app.

Comment: @Sourabh Yes, and performance is better when using separate INSERT's with some options like IGNORE or DELAYED (depends on your code) so you'll have parallel INSERT into two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

if its for only these two tables. Why dont you create a single table having all these columns in one as

```
>table message
id(int auto incr)
body(varchar)
sender(int ) comment 'user id of sender'
receiver(int) comment 'user id of receiver'
time(datetime)
```

then it will be like the way you want.

Comment: I can't bcoz if I do it this way, when a user will send a message to multiple receivers, the whole message will be copied again and again for each receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with GolezTrol or otherwise if you want an optimized performance for your query perhaps you may choose to use Stored Procedures

Answer (score 0):

Indeed combining those two inserts wouldn't be possible. While you van use JOIN in get queries, you can't combine insert queries. If your really worrying about performance, isn't there anyway to join those two tables together? As far is I can see there's no point in keeping them separated; there both about the message. 
As stated before, executing a second insert query isn't that much of a server load by the way.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you cannot really update multiple tables at once. And, you should not really be worried about performance, unless you are inserting thousands of messages in a short period of time.

Now, there is one thing you could worry about. Imagine, you first insert the message body, and then try to insert the receiver/sender IDs. Suppose first succeeds, while second (for whatever reason) fails. That would corrupt your data a bit. To avoid that, you can use transactions, e.g.

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $connection);
//your code
mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection);
```

That would ensure that either both inserts get into the database, or neither do. If you are using PDO, look into http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php for examples.